# Magento 1 How to modify transactional email template?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add one more new variable in the Order email template, can anyone suggest me where to go (path) and edit the template?

Actually, what I want to do,

1. In the product page need to display the dropdown beside "Qty" dropdown which is mandatory, if the user didn't select the couldn't allow to next step **add to cart**
2. Based on the selection I need to bring that value to the front end in the order template, which show's the snapshot.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your transactional email templates from the below location:

> app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html
>
> app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html

Also you need to override the function **queueNewOrderEmail()** from below location:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Then pass your new variable from above class and call that variable on your template files.

**UPDATED:**

You need to copy the below file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

To your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

And add your code according to your requirement. You need to locate the code in this file only.

Comment: Found template but that layout handle is didn't find that code like the below: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: I want to add one of my product name.

Comment: On which place?

Comment: Please, check my question & description, I mentioned very clearly.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, checking!

Answer (score 0):

You can find email template in `magento admin>System>Transactional Emails` section.If you want to create new template then click on Add New Template button. Check following attached image for add new variable.

[image: Check image here.]

Comment: Not found for "new order" template in the given path under Transactional emails.